# Masking window's background with non-trivial shape using winapi

Tags: winapi

I have winapi application with single window which background is like
[this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/16/backgroundkn.png/)

But problem is that shape it non-trivial. It isn't just rectangle. It is
[complex mask](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/840/foreground2r.png/)

What functions do I need to achieve something like this?
 I'm interested only in those relevant to masking background. Mask will be moved using mouse but this part is fairly easy once I got mask.

Hope you like my paint skillz

Comment: It would help to know what you mean by "mask". Do you mean you want a rectangular window with star-shaped "cutouts" where anything behind that window shows though?

Comment: Yes, everything behind mask ( that star-shaped shape ) should be visible and everything else(rest of client's rectangle) should be hidden - painted black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the shape of a window (for painting and hit-testing) using [SetWindowRgn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

You can create a [region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from rectangles, ellipses or polygons and combine them to create more complex shapes.